# Proper CSS to align 2 divs for whatever screen size, second div has a ::before element attached

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

```
.logo {
text-align: center;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.bubble{
    background-color: rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
    background: rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    -pie-background:  rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #B2B2B2;
    min-height: 100px;
width: 350px;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
background: rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
-pie-background:  rgba(0, 36, 97, 0.4);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);

    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
     transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

On a desktop screen it looks like this (which is the desired):

[image]

On a larger desktop screen it looks like this:

[image]

When browser window is re-sized the 2 divs overlap, and on a mobile device the .bubble div goes to the next line.

What is the correct way to align them together and make the .bubble div flexible to stretch vertically when window is re-sized?

Comment: fiddle it out . else ull not get any response from images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no html is provided, I will just talk about the theory here.

In general,

1. The bubble should be wrapped in a div (call it bubble-wrapper) with float:left, margin-left, and position:relative. The bubble-wrapper should be placed next to logo div
2. The bubble is a div with a margin-left large enough for the triangle, a min-width and a min-height. It's also where the border should be drawn
3. The triangle is a position:absolute div with left:0, top:0 inside bubble-wrapper
4. Wrap the inner text in bubble as needed.